# Visual Studio Code Editor Settings

Tags: visual-studio

I have accidently enabled these dotted lines that exist on the left of each line of code as in the image below, I would like to undo it, I have tried to reset VS setting but it stayed there, any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit -> Advanced -> untick View White Space

Or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.